# How to auto-scroll a related html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 2 tables, and they are related, because they are showing the same in different languages. When I press `Key down` or `Key up`, the item inside my clicked table moves and scrolls down, but not the related one. How can I make this?

Here is a piece of the html5 code:

```
<div id="first_table">
    <table id="first_header">
      <tr>
        <th class="field_1">1</th>                
        <th class="field_2">2</th>
        <th class="field_3">3</th>
        <th class="field_4">4</th>
        <th class="field_5">5</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="first_table_container">
      <table id="first_text_table">
       <tbody id="first_text_table_body">
       </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="first_current">
     <textarea id="first_current_text" ></textarea>                           
     </div> 
</div>

<div id="second_table">
    <table id="second_header">
      <tr>
        <th class="field_1">1</th>                
        <th class="field_2">2</th>
        <th class="field_3">3</th>
        <th class="field_4">4</th>
        <th class="field_5">5</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="second_table_container">
      <table id="second_text_table">
       <tbody id="second_text_table_body">
       </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="second_current">
     <textarea id="second_current_text" ></textarea>                           
     </div> 
</div>
```

Here the CSS:

```
#first_table
{
width:90%;
float: left;
border-radius: 5px;
border-color: black;                                
border-collapse: collapse;    
margin-right:33px;
margin-bottom: 1%; 
}       
#second_table
{
width:90%;
float: right;
border-radius: 5px;
border-color: black;                                
border-collapse: collapse;    
margin-right:30px;
margin-bottom: 1%; 
}
#first_table_container, #second_table_container 
{
height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px;
border-color: #5e5e5e;                           
border-bottom-width:1px;
}
```

And now the javasrcipt (jQuery) code:

```
if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up
                var index = $('#first_text_table_body tr > td').index();
                $('#second_text_table_body').scrollTo(index);
}
```

I've tried `scrollTo()`, but I can't make it works properly. My goal is, if I press `key up`, my first list scrolls up and the second list has to scroll up as well.

Thank you!

Comment: the fastest way to get help with this is to supply a working fiddle...

Comment: also why do you use a table for headers? and a different table for the rows?

Comment: @LiranBo I had problems with the indexes and this came to me

Answer (score 2):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/89du77gy/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="first_table">
    <table id="first_header">
        <tr>
            <th class="field_1">1</th>
            <th class="field_2">2</th>
            <th class="field_3">3</th>
            <th class="field_4">4</th>
            <th class="field_5">5</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="first_table_container">
        <table id="first_text_table">
            <tbody id="first_text_table_body">
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="first_current">
        <textarea id="first_current_text"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="second_table">
    <table id="second_header">
        <tr>
            <th class="field_1">1</th>
            <th class="field_2">2</th>
            <th class="field_3">3</th>
            <th class="field_4">4</th>
            <th class="field_5">5</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="second_table_container">
        <table id="second_text_table">
            <tbody id="second_text_table_body"></tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>abc</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>abc</td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="second_current">
        <textarea id="second_current_text"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#first_table {
    width:45%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-right:33px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
#second_table {
    width:45%;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
#first_table_container, #second_table_container {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-color: #5e5e5e;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
            $("#first_table_container").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            });
            $("#second_table_container").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            });
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40) { //down
            $("#first_table_container").animate({
                scrollTop: 200
            });
            $("#second_table_container").animate({
                scrollTop: 200
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I used `scrollTop` instead, it just need a value of where to go. my solution is just to get you starting. you can continue this to calculate the scrollTop value you want to set on each click..

You should also clean the code.

Comment: @Sergi if it worked for you please accept the answer